# Which philosophers have contradicted Nietzsche?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, nietzsche

These days I'm becoming tired of the recurrent introduction of Friedrich Nietzsche as the epitome of the philosophical genius, the revolutionary whose ideas have never been as relevant as now and the prophet of the supposed decadence of our time (that may not be a universal tendency but I'm French and there is unfortunately a form of veneration for this tradition of philosophy in France).

Who are known to be the most prominent contradictors of Nietzsche? I'm looking for authors, books, texts. In particular I would be very interested in any material coming from analytical philosophy.

I know Russell gave a negative review in his History of Western Philosophy but it seems he had a limited view of Nietzsche's actual work and may have been biased by Elisabeth Nietzsche's rearrangement of her brother's work. Heiddeger is also said to have criticised Nietzsche's position but as far as I understand he is largely seen as a sort of continuator of Nietzsche's tradition.

Comment: @gordon I don't get the point of your different comments on Kojeve, Strauss, Lyotard etc as well as your questioning about who may have been a fascist or a conservative. In what does any part of this answers my question? I'm not asking for a philosopher with a given political alignment but for someone contradicting a specific philosophical system. On Quine, it's not clear to me if you mean that he actually criticized N (if yes, do you have any reference?) or if you just imply he would certainly have done it if anybody had asked.

Comment: @Gordon: None of this is answering my question. I'm not asking about the reasons postmodernist were interested in N, or if Marx is read again in France, if this is good news, or if rich people prefer Nietzsche, Hegel, Prosecco wine, reality television or macramé. So please stay focused on the original question

Comment: Stanley Rosen in America wrote a whole book against Nietzsche, 
“Nihilism: a Philosophical Essay” (Yale University Press, 1969). But he was not an analytical philosopher. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Rosen  Frankly it is not a very sophisticated book, even though Rosen was usually a good philosopher.

Comment: @William: The answers are clearly no and no. Where are those insinuations supposed to bring us?

Comment: Supposed to bring that the first sentence isn’t so true in circles out of pop philosophy. The first tags here for example about specific people are Kant and Aristoteles, Nietzsche shows up way after close to Platon.

Comment: @William: My question is explicitely mentioning the French context. To be more precise French press and intellectuals. I'm not refering to the popularity of philosophers on stackexchange. However I'm very glad if people here are far less obsessed with Nietzsche. That said, it seems to me that whatever could be the general perception of him, it does not invalidate my question.